# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 ----ionic3

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

The data can be inserted into the database and the JSON also can be generated very well but why is 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1' thrown?

The problem has been shown in the picture

[image: problem has been shown in picture]

signup.ts

```
signup(){
     this.authService.postData(this.userData,'signup').then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;
      if(this.responseData.userData){
      console.log(this.responseData);
      localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      }
      else{ {swal({
        title: "User already exist.Please try again",
         })
         } }
    }, (err) => { ;
      // Error log
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you post the result of the   console.log(this.responseData)?

Comment: @Melchia there has not the result of the console, only has unexpected token < in json at position 1.From the picture u can saw it

Comment: Just before the error there is a console.log result. Ican see it in your image but I need to know the full result

Comment: that one console is for my login part not the signup part

Comment: Test your rest api with a rest client separately. See if it returns a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting BR tag in your response, and because of that it can't be parsed to JSON, so remove the

```
>  <br />batman2@gmail.comhere
```

tag from your response.

Comment: Nice one I didn't notice he was reading the preview ( by mistake). He didn't want to share the result of the  console.log(this.responseData)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate JSON response in your service by using rxjs **map** operater:

`this.http.get(YOUR_URL).map(res => res.json());`